# Progress bar displaying execution of a method

Tags: c#, multithreading, compact-framework

I don't know how to display a execution of a method in Compact .Net Framework. 
For example  I have a method (eg. **Upload()** or **Print()**) which takes some time (in some cases it is a big interval) to finish.I want that the user can see the progression of the time-consuming task (eg. **Upload()**) on a progress bar.

I tried doing this with `Thread` and `ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItembut` but i'm stuck.
 The problem is that i don't know how to  sync the thread of the method and the progressbar.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this help:

```
ProgressBar pg = new ProgressBar();
pg.Maximum = 100;
pg.Step = 1;

this.Controls.Add(pg);

new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
    {
        // Replace with your code:
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if (pg.InvokeRequired)
                pg.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() =>
                    {
                        pg.PerformStep();
                    }));
            else
                pg.PerformStep();
        }
    })).Start();
```

this part is important, or you get an exception:

```
if (pg.InvokeRequired)
    pg.Invoke(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            pg.PerformStep();
        }));
else
    pg.PerformStep();
```

Comment: This is it. I'm struggling where to insert a thread of a method that is running while the progress bar is updating.

Answer (score 2):

You can fork your time consuming work into a new thread in that thread you can determine your progress and fire an even like `ProgressChanged(int actualProgress)` and then Handle that event in the UI and set the progressbar according to the value from the event. you will have to do some dispaching at that point.

Comment: Could you elaborate this,please? I tried a similar thing, but the CF framework doesn't have the IsAlive() method for threads.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "sync the thread of the method and the progressbar" I can only guess that you get an exception when you try to change the value of the progressbar? 
If that is the problem, you will have to use the thread-safe way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728.aspx

Comment: Meaning:The progress bar must be progressing while the method is running. When the method exits the progress bar stops. It can also simulate the execution of the method.It's important that the progress bar must start when the method is started and end when the execution of the method is over . I didn't get any exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking at the [BackgroundWorker?](http://dotnetperls.com/backgroundworker)

You can run threads and update a progress bar.

**Edit**

Didn't realise it was for CF, but there's an article I found when having a browse and I don't know if you have come across this before:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446488.aspx

Comment: No problem :) I  used exactly that document as a reference. But i have no clue how to track the progress.

Comment: Not really done much in CF but after some searching I have found this custom class created here:

http://www.danielmoth.com/Blog/backgroundworker-sample.aspx